# Optimizing Redshift Performance for Grouping Operation

Tags: database-design, amazon-redshift

I currently find myself in the challenge that a simple "group by" takes around 2 minutes. Here what I did:

1. I create a table

```
create table devdb.raw_external_listings.pq_base_account_table
(
sap_id varchar(50) 
,account_name nvarchar(max) 
,Lead_source_code smallint not null
,company_id nvarchar(50) 
,company_name nvarchar(max) 
,description nvarchar(max) 
,Lead_source_name nvarchar(max) 
,Source_Code nvarchar(50) not null
,Source_Name nvarchar(max) 
,source_country varchar(20) 
,business_model varchar(20) 
,posting_ID bigint not null
,Date_Posted date  not null 
,posted_year int not null
,posted_month int not null
,Work_Type varchar(max) 
,Job_Country varchar(20) 
,joblocation nvarchar(max) 
,class_id int 
,unique_clid varchar(max) not null  sortkey
--,unique_clid bigint not null  sortkey
,ultimate_parent_sap_id varchar(50) 
,ultimate_parent_name nvarchar(max)
,ultimate_legal_parent_sap_id varchar(50) 
,ultimate_legal_parent_sap_name varchar(max) 
,account_bl varchar(50) 
,postal_code varchar(50) 
,emp_resp_login varchar(50) 
,full_name nvarchar(max) 
)
```

2. I inserted the data (54mio rows)
3. I run my group by

```
SELECT count(distinct unique_clid),count(distinct company_id), count(distinct work_type), posted_year, posted_month
FROM devdb.raw_external_listings.pq_base_account_table with (nolock)
GROUP by posted_year, posted_month
order by posted_year, posted_month
```

Is there an approach to optimize the performance of these basic aggregation methods?

THX
Lazloo

Comment: how did you "insert" your data? make sure that redshift has set correct compression on your columns (it would if you used "COPY" command

Comment: What relevant ways have you researched so far to improve SQL & Redshift performance of such queries? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is concept of sort_key and dist_key in Redshift which is very critical for optimisation on Redshift. These keys define how the data is stored in Redshift for a table.

In your case currently Redshift is choosing these keys by default which may or may not be efficient as per user's use case. Please go through below links and design your tables accordingly.

Steps to consider
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-tuning-tables.html

For sort-keys:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html

For dist-keys:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the dist key advice above:

With this setup your data for the same year / month is scattered across Redshift cluster nodes. I would imagine that to count distinct values the engine would get unique values on every node but then it has to send these lists to the leader node to combine them into master unique list, and finally count. If you distribute your data on year or month column it might finalize count distinct operations on every node independently, making the process faster.

You could also sort data on the columns you group by but the main thing is to distribute probably.

No need to sort by `unique_clid`, at least for this query.